# Multiple statements in MySQL THEN

Tags: mysql, case

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
BEGIN
SELECT CASE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 where c1 = p2)
WHEN 0 THEN INSERT INTO t1(c1) VALUES (p2)
    INSERT INTO t2(c1, c2) VALUES (p1, LAST_INSERT_ID());
END
END
```

The goal is to write a stored procedure that checks to see if an item exists in a table, and if not, creates it in that table, and then takes the autoincrement key from that insert and creates a row in another table.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `IF EXISTS(SELECT..) THEN.. ELSE` is a valid construction within a BEGIN END block.So yes you can write that procedure

Comment: The procedure above gives an error. Why?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways Just that there is an error near `VALUES (p2)
    INSERT `

Comment: @soandos did you find a solution for your question?